# Searching for object in IList or IQueryable

Tags: linq, select, iqueryable, ilist

I need to find a match of an item in a IQueryable list. I have a list as follows:

```
IQueryable<EventItem> eventItems = new Queryable<EventItem>();
EventItem eventItem1 = new EventItem("Event 1");
EventItem eventItem2 = new EventItem("Event 2");
eventItems.Add(eventItem1);
eventItems.Add(eventItem2);
```

I now want to find the event in the list by passing in an EventItem like eventItem2. How do I search and return item something like
EventItem found = eventItems.Select(eventItem2);

Cheers,

S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq proviedes a .Where method that lets you pass in a lambda expression to evaluate the item you're looking for.

```
EventItem found = eventItems.Where(e => e == eventItem2).SingleOrDefault();
```

found could be null, so you just need to check for that to see whether it was found in the queryable/list

Comment: you just caught the answer before I fixed it ;-)

Comment: Thanks Joel, always simple when you see it

Answer (score 7):

using LINQ you can do:

```
EventItem found = eventItems.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Name == "Event 2");
```

Assuming that the name for the EventItem is exposed via a Name property.

The `item => [code]` part is where you provide a method that returns true/false, to decide whether the items match or not.

Comment: Shame this wasn't accepted, it was first, more succint/readable, more efficient and spelt correctly on the first try!

Comment: Cheers!  Tho as long as people see the answer, it's all good.